# Question about public availability of human SNP dataset with country of origin

Tags: database, snp, public-databases, human-genome

Is there a publicly available data set for humans SNPs, preferably together with the country of origin? If so, could someone please point me towards it.

I've looked through other questions on the site and have been unable to find a similar one. I don't know how sensitive human SNP data is, so I'm not sure if this would be public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[1000 genomes](https://www.internationalgenome.org/data-portal/data-collection/30x-grch38), [HGDP](https://www.internationalgenome.org/data-portal/data-collection/hgdp) and [SGDP](https://www.simonsfoundation.org/simons-genome-diversity-project/) all contain SNP data from individuals where the country of origin is known.

They all have slightly different numbers of people from different populations (1000 genomes and HGDP have more individuals in each pop, but fewer pops, and SGDP is the opposite).

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Do you know if any of these websites have .vcf files already ready to download? Or will I need to follow a pipeline to convert the .fastq files to .vcf?

Comment: Yes the 1000 genomes files can be found on this ftp mirror http://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/data_collections/1000G_2504_high_coverage/working/20201028_3202_raw_GT_with_annot/ - although the total vcfs tend to be quite big

Comment: hgdp vcf can be found here ftp://ngs.sanger.ac.uk/production/hgdp/hgdp_wgs.20190516/